# Rails form not causing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been working on a rails form and think I've messed something up, but cant put my finger on what.

To give an overview. I have created a 1 page site with a contact form at the bottom. I have looked around for similar questions and they seem to have the contact form on another page with another controller, so can't find an answer for me. I know I've missed something, but can't figure out what.

I get an error which states

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

My **main_controller.rb** is as follows

```
class MainController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    @contact.request = request
    if @contact.deliver
      redirect_to thank_you_path
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Cannot send message.'
      render :index
    end
  end

  private

  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :phone, :message)
  end

end
```

**contact.rb** is

```
class Contact < MailForm::Base
  attribute :name,      :validate => true
  attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  attribute :phone,     :validate => true
  attribute :message,   :validate => true

  def headers
    {
      subject: "Quote Form",
      to: "email-addy@gmail.com",
      from: %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
    }
  end

end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@contact, layout: :horizontal, label_col: "col-sm-2", control_col: "col-sm-10") do |f| %>
 form template here
<% end %>
```

**routes/rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :main, only: [:new, :create]
  root 'main#index'
  get '/thank-you'          => 'main#thank-you'
end
```

Comment: You don't have `@contact` defined in the index action of the controller.

Comment: you need to initiate '@contact' at your index action because on index.html.erb '@contact' is nil OR replace '@contact' with Contact.new in your form

Comment: @j-dexx How would I go about this? I've tried to add it to the main controller as def index

Comment: As you thought, `@contact = Contact.new` in the index action

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a instance of Contacts in new method and calling that instance with form_for on index.html.erb that's why you get `@contact` **nil**, just move this code `@contact = Contact.new` to index method/action where you actually calling the form for with th Contact instance.